# Excel Calculations

Tags: excel

Is there a way I can have an excel track the number of times a number has been entered?  For instance, if the number 1 is entered into a column 10 times it would display that in the legend.  And if the number 10 was entered into a column 2 times it would display that total in the legend.

The goal is to track each number as a unique integer 1 - 35.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use  `=COUNTIF(A:A,"10")` to count the number of 10s in Column A.

But you'll need 35 COUNTIF functions in 35 cell, and that only for 1 Column.

How do you plan to display that Legend?

Comment: thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for.  I didn't know how to incorporate the unique number into the function call.

Comment: I have everything working now, thank you for that.  I was wondering is there a way to have the countif function dynamically update based on the sort filter? @Francis P

Comment: I figured it out, for those interested it would be =SUMPRODUCT(SUBTOTAL(3,OFFSET(G4:K608,ROW(G4:K608)-MIN(ROW(G4:K608)),,1))*(G4:K608=1))/5

Comment: @need2nobasis - I assume you don't have any partially populated rows - i.e. rows with some blanks and some values, otherwise your formula can miscount. This version may be preferable because it gives an accurate count of 1s in visible rows, with or without blanks in the data - `=SUMPRODUCT((SUBTOTAL(3,OFFSET(G4:K608,ROW(G4:K608)-MIN(ROW(G4:K608)),,1))>0)*(G4:K608=1))`